# How do I enable GMP on Mac OS X / PHP 7?

Tags: php, composer-php, php-7, gmp, php-ini

I'm using PHP 7 and Mac High Sierra.  I'm trying to install and enable GMP.  I installed via

```
brew install homebrew/php/php70-gmp
```

but when I try and enable the module through the php.ini (/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini) file, I'm failing . I tried uncommenting the line

```
extension=php_gmp.dll
```

but I get this error when running composer

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.27_19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_gmp.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.27_19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_gmp.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

How do I enable GMP in my php.ini file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some `.dll` file is not usual for a Mac system. Can you have a look at the folder `/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.27_19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/` to see if there is any other GMP related file? Probably, you should add the extension through

```
extension=gmp.so
```

Comment: Although that particluar directory didn't exist on my system, adding that line to my php.ini file worked (at least I don't see taht same error when running composer).

Comment: Good to know - and installing all that packages now works completely?

Comment: Unfortunately, no -- I still get that error, "The requested package bitwasp/stratum 1.0.0 is satisfiable by bitwasp/stratum[1.0.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability." so still Googling to try and find the answer to that one.

Comment: Okay, getting back to that in the other question ;)